# how to create tabpanels and their content inside of a v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

I'm working with `Vue 3` and `Bootstrap 5`.

I want to have some `Tabpanels` inside of a `v-for`. All of these `Tabs` should have a different content.

So I've tried to put my `Tabs` inside of a `v-for` and my `Content` too.

But it wont work out right now (I could not see the Content) and I could not figure it out whats the problem.. and I'm not sure right now if I also need two `v-fors` or if it's possible to get it all in one.

Thanks for your help.

```
<ul class="mt-3 nav nav-pills" id="all_tabs" role="tablist">
  <div v-for="item in input" :key="item.id">
    <li class="ms-1 nav-item" role="presentation">
      <button
        class="nav-link active"
        :id="item.id"
        data-bs-toggle="tab"
        :data-bs-target="'#tab' + item.id"
        type="button"
        role="tab"
        :aria-controls="'tab' + item.id"
      >
        {{ item.name }}
      </button>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

```
<div class="tab-content mt-3" id="all_tabs">
  <div v-for="item in input" :key="item.id">
    <div class="tab-pane fade" :id="'tab' + item.id" role="tabpanel">
      <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I do following in `mounted` just to be clear how `input` is created.

```
data() {
  return {
    array: [1,2],
    input: [],
  }
}

mounted() {
  this.array.map((i) => {
    this.input.push({
      id: i, 
      name: "Input" + i,
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: What is your outcome? So what exactly does not work with your code. And btw `map` is not the correct funciton here you should use `.forEach` for this. (in `mounted`)

Comment: my outcome is nothing. I see my ```Tabs``` but I could not see content inside of the ```tabs```. Thank you will change it! :)

Comment: have you imported `popper.js` or `bootstrap.bundle.js`? And to be honest i would recommend using a component-library like [PrimeVue](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/). If you don't want to use a library and you have indeed imported the need JavaScript for Bootstrap - let me know and I'll try and create an example for you

Comment: I've imported ```popper.js``` - actually I don't want to use another component libary in that case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my code to make it work:

> Note: I am using `<script setup>` because I know it better :) - it works the same with your Options-API approach.

**script**

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const input = ref([]);
const array = ref([1,2]);

array.value.forEach((i) => {
    input.value.push({
        id: i,
        name: "Input" + i,
    });
});
</script>
```

**template** (the important part):

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
    <li v-for="(item, index) of input" class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link"
                :class="index === 0 ? 'active': null"
                :id="`${item.name}-tab`"
                data-bs-toggle="pill"
                :data-bs-target="`#${item.name}`"
                type="button"
                role="tab"
                :aria-controls="item.name"
                :aria-selected="index === 0"
        >
            {{ item.name }}
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
    <div v-for="(item, index) of input"
         class="tab-pane fade"
         :class="index === 0  ? 'show active': null"
         :id="item.name" role="tabpanel"
         aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab"
    >
        {{ item.name }}
    </div>
</div>
```

**main.js**

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Also note that [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) has a different usecases than [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) - in your case you should use `forEach`.